# Why do I get a "cannot read property of undefined" error when the data is defined?

Tags: javascript, fetch, next.js, rest

```js
export async function getPrices() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/crypto/BTCUSD/price?token=Tpk_1d3fd3aee0b64736880534d05a084290"
  );
  const quote = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { quote }
  };
}

export default function IndexPage({ quote }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{quote.price}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to return the price of a cryptocurrency using an API called IEX Cloud, which seems to work fine when tested in Postman. My problem is I can't seem to return the data on my Next.js app.

Please find the MRE here:

[image: Edit nostalgic-wave-6sidm]

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined`, but if you access the route in a browser or Postman you can see there is a 'price' defined.

https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/crypto/BTCUSD/price?token=Tpk_1d3fd3aee0b64736880534d05a084290

`<p>{quote.price}</p>` is the line in my code that throws up the error.

I'm sure it's a very obvious misunderstanding on my part but I am really stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not an external site. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Hopefully I have made a Stack Snippet but just in case I have left the original link to CodeSandbox which works far better IMO. Figuring out how to explain the problem can sometimes feel more difficult than understanding the problem in the first place.

Comment: @Anthony i've posted the answer, you can check and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the function name `getPrices` to `getServerSideProps`

Here is your refactor code in codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-frost-lb9xm?file=/pages/index.js

or you can create separate function for `getPrices` and call it in `getServerSideProps`

Comment: Thanks, that does work. Unfortunately my MRE doesn't show that I am actually trying to execute the code on a [slug].js that has getStaticProps() and won't allow both. When I put your refactor code into getStaticProps() it gives me the original problem. To complicate things further, I am also calling a GraphQL query using GraphQLClient from GraphCMS. Is it because I cannot fetch two APIs?

Comment: I've done it! Rearranged the code inside getStaticProps(). I'll try and update my code above to reflect the changes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's Good @Anthony Thanks.